# Possibly Misunderstanding IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED With Custom RoleVoter

Tags: grails, spring-security

Our system needs to allow users to be members across multiple organizations and have different roles for each organization.  My UserRole class has been modified to the following:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {
   User user
   Role role
   Organization organization
}
```

In order for this to work, I had to create a custom Voter which looks like this:

```
class OrganizationRoleVoter extends RoleVoter {

  @Override
  public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    int result = ACCESS_ABSTAIN
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = extractAuthorities(authentication)
    GrailsWebRequest request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
    Organization selectedOrganization = (Organization) request.session.getAttribute("selectedOrganizationSession")

    attributes.each {ConfigAttribute attribute ->
      if (this.supports(attribute)) {
        result = ACCESS_DENIED
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
          if (attribute.attribute.equals(authority.authority)) {
            def user = User.findByUsername(authentication.name)
            def role = Role.findByAuthority(authority.authority)
            if (UserRole.findByUserAndOrganizationAndRole(user, selectedOrganization, role)) {
              result = ACCESS_GRANTED
              break
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result
  }

  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication.getAuthorities();
  }

}
```

The problem we're having is with the Remember Me cookie.  If using it, during some requests, (not all), the app is forcing a full authentication. I've only seen this happen to ajax requests, but our app is 90% ajax so I can't say that is the case conclusively.  However, I have all my user level controllers annotated like this:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
```

(Every use is required the ROLE_USER role, and can have other roles if necessary).

This is the config:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.voterNames = [
    'organizationRoleVoter', 'authenticatedVoter'
]

grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames =
  ['rememberMeServices',
      'securityContextLogoutHandler',
      'securityEventListener']
```

So I'm not sure at this point why the application is requiring a full authentication if I'm telling it to allow the remember me cookie authentication.  Am I misreading the docs?  Or did I implement the voter incorrectly?

Comment: The voter looks correct. Are you sure that you're using IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED *everywhere* ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've quadruple checked.

Comment: Is that a case happens when session times out? Since the value of selectedOrganization is taken from a session variable.

Comment: No, it actually returns an access denied error because spring security thinks the user needs to register fully.  I log in, I make about 3 ajax requests, then it happens.  Our session is set to timeout in 2 hours.  Not 30 seconds.

Comment: Did you register your voter in resources.groovy and config.groovy?

Comment: Yes, the voter code is being called. Otherwise a lot more would not be working.